# Start, stop and repeat a Service at scheduled time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I managed to start and repeat a service using the `AlarmManager`. But once the service is started at a scheduled time, I want it to stop after suppose 5 hours and then repeat the same thing again the next day.

Any leads on this?

Comment: You can do it by using AlarmManager...

Comment: how? i know i can stop the service using the `cancel` method but i want to repeat the alarm manager the next day.

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager.cancel() method will not stop the service...try like this.

When your service started in the onCreate() of the service() schedule an alarm which fires a broadcast after 5hrs. So now in broadcast receiver stop the service using context.stopSerVice() method..

Answer (score 0):

I created a handler which stops the service after say 5 hours. This worked for me.

```
private boolean handler = new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        stopSelf();
        Log.e("DEMO:","Service Stopped");
    }
}, 5*60*60*1000);
```

The repeat interval would always be > service running time.
Now, the service would stop after 5 hours and the `AlarmManager` would start it again after 24 hours.

Hoping it made sense and is a correct way of implementing it.